# jmeter recording throws error when launching main screen

Tags: jmeter

I used jmeter recorder for recording some screen interactions. When I run the test in jmeter, the View results tree shows this error on a few samplers-

//EX[2,1,["com.i2.tm.ui.ria.client.exception.DataException/3457339990","FORGED_REQUEST"],0,7]

The loading of the page and then the login is all successful. Only going to the main screen, i get this error. Anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forgot to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of at least one of the dynamic parameters responsible for [CSRF protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

My expectation is that after login the system under test sends you a [CSRF Token](https://brightsec.com/blog/csrf-token/) which you need to:

1. Extract with a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Replace recorded token with the variable from the previous step

More information: [What is CSRF & How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-csrf-load-testing)